# Run functions inside model.py - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to execute the function named `Average_Health()` inside `models.py` to insert it's i.e. `Average_Health()`returned value. I don't want to execute the function inside `views.py` because there's such a condition that several `views.py` will this same task.

It's just a sample code to understand:

```
class myModal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

    earning = models.IntegerField(max_length=150, default=1600)
    def Average_Health():
        return (earning-2500)
    health = models.IntegerField(max_length=1000, default=Average_Health())
```

What I want.

1. Get the value sent by view.py for models.py
2. Manipulate that data and insert that  manipulated data inside model.py FIELDs.

Comment: I don't want to import it codes everywhere. I just want to do it via models.py.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get Average_Health as attribute you can use property decorator like this:

```
class MyModal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    earning = models.IntegerField(max_length=150, default=1600)
    
    @property
    def Average_Health(self):
        return (self.earning - 2500)
```

but if you want set a value on health field as default and Manipulate that data in view.py you can do like this:

```
class MyModal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    earning = models.IntegerField(max_length=150, default=1600)
    health = models.IntegerField(max_length=1000)
```

and set health value in view.py when you get data from request.
like this:

```
def my_view(request):
    data = request.POST
    MyModel.objects.create(name=data.get('name'), earning=data.get('earning'), health=data.get('earning') - 2500)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```